# Python: xPath not available in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-2.7, elementtree, iterparse

I am trying to parse iTunes Playlist by using `iterparse()` of `ElementTree` but getting following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Code is given below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
context = ET.iterparse(file,events=("start", "end"))
    # turn it into an iterator
    context = iter(context)
    # get the root element
    event, root = context.next()
    for event, elem in context:
        z = elem.xpath(".//key")
        elem.clear()
        root.clear()
    print z
```

What I am doing wrong? File is too big so I have to use `iterparse()` anyway.

Comment: Try `elem.findall(".//key")` instead of `elem.xpath(".//key")`.

Comment: `elem.clear()`, among other things, removes all sub-elements. Have you tried removing `elem.clear()` and `root.clear()` and putting `print z` **inside** the `for` loop?

Comment: Ok yes it returns within loop when I commented the clear() code. What do you suggest?

Comment: Why do you need the `clear()` method calls?

Comment: I read here: http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm It is for lxml. I thought it will be issue for elementTree in built-in library too. Check under heading **Incremental Parsing**

Comment: I understand. However, you will need to do **all** the processing you need with `z` **before** you call `clear()` because it will be lost after that.

Comment: This is plist XML: http://pastebin.com/gU5tX9nR I have to play with each dict block to get relevant song information. I have now changed findall() to **z = elem.findall(".//dict/dict/key")**, checking it now

Comment: Ok sorted it out: Here is the updated code: http://pastie.org/5401946  Love you bro! Can you make it an ANSWER so that I can accept?

Comment: One issue I found with ElementTree that it works _sequentially_. The pList document(http://pastebin.com/gU5tX9nR) contains tags like _keys_ , _integer_ and _string_. There's no way to fetch particular string/integer tag by doing some *next* operation. How do I tackle tht?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) [provides limited support for XPath expressions](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm) for its [`Element`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) class [`find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find), [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) and [`findtext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext) methods (there's no `xpath` method: that's why you are getting an error).

Also, if you call `clear()` on an element to conserve used memory, you need to do it only **after** you've finished processing the element and all its children.

Therefore, you need to to change your code to something similar to the following:

```
for event, elem in context:
    for child in elem.findall(".//key"):
        # process child
    elem.clear()
    root.clear()
```

Comment: Thanks for your generous help.